# Linear independent set of the right cardinality is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

In the case of vector space over a field this result is trivially true. If we assume the IBN property for commutative rings, is there a simple proof to this result for a free module $A^n$ over a commutative ring $A$?

(Note that for any free module $A^n$ over a commutative ring $A$, every generator set of $A$ with cardinality $n$ is a basis. Let’s assume we can also use this result.)

Comment: It's only true for finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @RobertShore Could you please give a conterexample? I never thought it could be wrong.

Comment: Let $V$ be the vector space of sequences of real numbers with finite support (in other words, only finitely many non-zero components).  Then $\{e_n~\vert~n \geq 2 \}$ is linearly independent and countably infinite but it is not a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  Take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=1$.  Then the set $\{2\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{Z}$, but it is not a basis.